# glsl Expected token ')', found 'identifier' with function mix

Tags: glsl, opengl-es

I have a Fragment shader that contains:

```
[...]
float c = texture2D(tex, tc).a;
float alpha = mix(0.0f, 1.0f, c);
gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 1, 1, alpha) * color;
```

This works fine on my desktop and Nexus 5. However I get an exception while running on a Wiko mobile:

```
0:22: L0001: Expected token ')', found 'identifier'
```

Line 22 is the line containing the mix function.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You seem to be missing a semicolon at the end of the line `float c = texture2D...` — is that present in the original? It could be that some platforms' shader compilers fix this common error automatically, but the one that's throwing the exception doesn't.

Comment: Thanks DMGregory, it was just a mistake when I pasted the code

Comment: Just by the way, do you have `#version` directive in the shader?

Comment: HolyBlackCat, I have a `#version 100` directive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your driver and GLSL version, the "f" suffix on floats may be illegal.  Change to:

```
float alpha = mix(0.0, 1.0, c);
```

As always, OS is irrelevant; you really **need** to say what **hardware** (in particular what **GPU**) you have.

Comment: Thanks, this was the issue. Next time I'll remember about the hardware and GPU :)

Comment: Sometimes OS matters, even within a single vendor's drivers. I've had Catalyst shader bugs that only manifested on one OS or another.

Comment: @LarsViklund - that's not the OS, it's the driver. The driver is OS-specific for sure, but it's still the driver.

Comment: @LeComteduMerde-fou I did deploy what was claimed to be identical drivers on Windows and Linux, upstream couldn't repro on Windows. Sometimes variations happen.