# GLSL Fragment Shader compiles fine on certain computers

Tags: opengl, glsl, fragment-shader

I got this piece of code in a fragment shader:

```
if (color.a < 0.01f)
    discard;
```

It runs fine on an older graphic card but can't even compile on my newer (maybe not new, but..) GTX 770. I got the most recent drivers and everything. The versions is correct. OpenGL 4.4. The shader compiles like normal if I remove the *discard* statement.

I've been searching around and I'm finding nothing about this. Does the *discard* just not work on certain graphic cards or what?

Comment: Can you obtain any information about the specific compilation error that's occurring?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [glsl Expected token ')', found 'identifier' with function mix](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/139304/glsl-expected-token-found-identifier-with-function-mix)

Comment: This might be better suited for Computer Graphics StackExchange

Comment: Really needs the whole shader and the `glGetShaderInfoLog()` messages to diagnose what's going wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the 'f' on your float constants.
It's not part of the GLSL language.

Source: [GLSL Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.1.10.pdf)

If you do not put a `#version NNN` pragma at the top of your shader it will compile according to GLSL 1.10 which does not supports the f suffix.

Source: [khronos wiki](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Core_Language_(GLSL)#Version)

Comment: Support for the 'f' suffix on float constants [was added to GLSL in version 1.2](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/GLSL_:_common_mistakes#NVIDIA_and_Types), more than a decade ago.

Comment: If you don't use the directive `#version` the shader will be compiled as version 1.1 which does not support the f suffix. And newer drivers tend to enforce this.